# Cordova App on Android not connecting to internet page?

Tags: android, cordova

I have an app that works fine on iOS. It uses Cordova and uses remote requests for some of its functions, however, on android, only on a device, it sometimes (pretty frequently) will not connect. It almost always works on the Genymotion emulator, except once, where I saw "NET CACHE ERR" or something similar to that in the Chrome dev tools console. (The default Android emulator cannot connect however.)

The calls are simple jQuery ajax post requests that work fine in the Genymotion emulator (all times except once), and fine in a browser and in the iOS Cordova app. Networking permissions are enabled and asked upon installation. Interestingly, it can still get the device id used for push notifications (which requires a network response, from what I can tell, however it could be misleading I suppose).

Example for the obligatory request:

```
function connect(){
    $.post('https://example.com/stuff.php', {
        'var': 'a variable!'
    }, function(data) {
        //internet request complete, confirm connection successful
        window.connected = true;
    });
}
window.connected = false;
setInterval(
    function(){
        if(window.connected==true){
            //yeah you connected
        }else{
            //naw you not connected homie
            connect();
        }
    },
    3500
);
```

Comment: share your code here

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin The code has now been shared!

Comment: How does it appear that "will not connect"? Does your error callback get called (the one that isn't in your example code)? IF the error callback is called, what is the error? Are you waiting for deviceReady event before you send your request?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. It has been updated to better demonstrate the method I'm using. It's an interval that tries to connect repeatedly until it connects. Then it sets a variable, does some stuff, and I use `clearInterval` to stop the interval.